# Gulp-angular, Gulp-less and bootstrap

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, gulp, gulp-less

I m working with gulp-angular yeoman generator and I m having some troubles dealing with gulp-less and bootstrap.

Actually, when trying to serve my files, I've got something like :

```
Message:
    Invalid mapping: {"generated":{"line":1293,"column":2},"source":"C:/Project/angularjs/ucom/remake/bower_components/bootstrap/less/type.less","original":{"line":1,"column":null},"name":null} in file undefined line no. undefined
Details:
    lineNumber: undefined
    fileName: undefined
```

I don't know what's happenning there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Faced the same issue. I was using gulp-sourcemaps while building my css files and looks like this is an issue with one of gulp-sourcemaps dependecies.

My hunch is convert-source-map.

In any case, disabling sourcemaps while building my css files did the trick for me.

Comment: How did you disable it ?

Comment: Just commented it out. :)